# Integration in R with integrate()

Tags: r

I try to use integrate() but get the following error

```
> integrate(function(x) x,lower=0,upper=1)
Error in (function (classes, fdef, mtable)  : 
  unable to find an inherited method for function ‘integrate’ for signature ‘"function"’
```

Is there anything wrong?

Comment: I typed in exactly the code that you have above and it worked just fine.  No errors,  correct answer (0.5).

Comment: @MBorg This is what I get on my side

Comment: @G5W So do you know what might cause this error?

Comment: Maybe if you did something like redefine `function`    I suggest that you restart R  and type in exactly your code before you run anything else. See if you still get the error.

Comment: @G5W Restarted and fixed. Confused. Thank you!

Comment: Another possibility is that you had loaded a package with a different definition of an `integrate` function which overrode the `stats::integrate()` that you are trying to use.

Comment: @pseudospin Exactly, thanks!